# An HTML doc makes AJAX request, server receives and then sends data back

Tags: ajax, go

The idea is to have an index.html, which is served via Apache web server, to send data to an IP address and port (AJAX) and waits for a response that it then displays; a "data" server, written in GO, awaits to receive data, then sends some data back via AJAX.

But somehow this does not work and does not generate output:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button1').click(function () {
          $.ajax({
            url: '127.0.0.1:8888/receive',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data : { post_data: 'hello world'},
            success : function(data) {
              $('#div1').html(data);
            },
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

    <div id='div1'>
      <h3>before</h3>
    </div>

    <input id='button1' type='button' value='AJAX POST to golang server'>

  </body>
</html>
```

**server.go:**

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
)

func receiveAjax(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 if r.Method == "POST" {
   data := r.FormValue("post_data")
   fmt.Println("Receive ajax post data string ", data)
   w.Write([]byte("<h2>after<h2>"))
 }
}

func main() {
 mux := http.NewServeMux()
 mux.HandleFunc("/receive", receiveAjax)

 http.ListenAndServe(":8888", mux)
}
```

Comment: What happens if you send the request "by hand"—say, by running `curl -siN http://127.0.0.1:8888 -X POST --data ''` (yeah, you may start with empty data)? In general, this is the approach to solving probems like these: decompose it into smaller pieces and deal with each of them in turn—repeating the decomposition recursively. If/when you've made sure the server works, fire up devtools in your browser and see what gets sent on the wire—if anything.

Comment: When you say, "this doesn't work". Did you try to start the server without an error? As @kostix said. `ListenAndServe` function returns an error if it can't start

Comment: @kostix
Thank you for your suggestions; however, I don't parse the root, but "/receive", which I guess you did not look at the server.go code I provided... in any case, when I added that, the console output was:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 05:38:26 GMT
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Comment: @Victor M 
After testing via curl, the server does receive the data, as such somehow the AJAX component does not seem to send any data to the server. I don't know how to fix the AJAX code so that it sends out the data correctly and then receives data back from the server...

Comment: What is printed to your servers' stdout when you copy the received request body to the console, e.g. `io.Copy(os.Stdout, r.Body)` ?

Comment: I have downloaded your code and try it in my localhost.
When I tried to click on the button it responds a 404 server error. So I have changed the url using the `http` protocol and it worked. Can you try it? Also, if you try on local, you should take care of CORS

Comment: @MikeyJ, the exact path in the URL is irrelevant: I tried to explain how to attack a problem at hand. The answer by Brits show this point rather clearly as well.

Answer (score 2):

`127.0.0.1:8888/receive` is not a valid URL (the AJAX call in your Javascript was failing with `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL"` but you were not catching the error). Adding an `error` function to the AJAX call makes it easier to find this kind of issue (as does the browsers dev tools).

The following works for me using `http://127.0.0.1:8888/receive` (note that I am serving the javascript from the go application to simplify things and avoid [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues - you may receive additional errors when serving the page from Apache but at least you should be able to see what is going wrong in the browser console).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

const html = `<html>
<head>
  <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#button1').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/receive',
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'html',
          data : { post_data: 'hello world'},
          error : function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          },
          success : function(data) {
            $('#div1').html(data);
          },
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <div id='div1'>
    <h3>before</h3>
  </div>

  <input id='button1' type='button' value='AJAX POST to golang server'>

</body>
</html>`

func receiveAjax(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        data := r.FormValue("post_data")
        fmt.Println("Receive ajax post data string ", data)
        w.Write([]byte("<h2>after<h2>"))
    }
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { w.Write([]byte(html)) })
    mux.HandleFunc("/receive", receiveAjax)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8888", mux)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work for you. As @Brits pointed, you should take care of CORS in jQuery, also, check for the errors in the javascript and golang code.

- index.html file

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
      <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#button1').click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/receive',
                  type: 'post',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  crossDomain: true,
                  data: {post_data: 'hello world'},
                  success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      $('#div1').html(data);
                  }
              });
          });
      });
  </script>

  <div id='div1'>
      <h3>before</h3>
  </div>

  <input id='button1' type='button' value='AJAX POST to golang server'>

  </body>
  ```
- server.go file

  ```
  package main

  import (
      "fmt"
      "net/http"
  )

  func receiveAjax(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      if r.Method == "POST" {
          data := r.FormValue("post_data")
          fmt.Println("Receive ajax post data string ", data)
          w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/html")
          w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
          w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
          w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
          w.Write([]byte("<h2>after<h2>"))
      }
  }

  func main() {
      mux := http.NewServeMux()
      mux.HandleFunc("/receive", receiveAjax)

      http.ListenAndServe(":8888", mux)
  }
  ```